# MAAS using PXE won't finish enlisting

Tags: maas, pxe

Following the instructions in https://maas.io/install on a blade server I got stuck on the enlisting step. The PXE booting loads the image but after some reasonable time waiting nothing else happens. The blade is not shown in the Machines section. This is the PXE boot screen:

```bsh
Intel(R) Boot Agent XE v2.3.58
Copyright (C) 1997-2015, Intel Corporation

CLIENT MAC ADDR: <BLADE_2_MAC_ADDRESS>  GUID: <GUID>
CLIENT IP: 10.10.10.191  MASK: 255.255.255.0  DHCP IP: 10.10.10.1
GATEWAY IP: 10.10.10.254

PXELINUX 6.03 PXE 20171017 Copyright (C) 1994-2014 H. Peter Anvin et al
Booting under MAAS direction...
nomodeset ro root=squash:http://10.10.10.1:5248/images/ubuntu/amd64/ga-18.04/bio
nic/daily/squashfs ip=::::maas-enlist:BOOTIF ip6=off overlayroot=tmpfs overlayro
ot_cfgdisk=disabled cc:{'datasource_list': ['MAAS']}end_cc cloud-config-url=http
://10.10.10.1:5240/MAAS/metadata/latest/enlist-preseed/?op=get_enlist_preseed ap
parmor=0 log_host=10.10.10.1 log_port=514
Loading ubuntu/amd64/ga-18.04/bionic/daily/boot-kernel... ok
Loading ubuntu/amd64/ga-18.04/bionic/daily/boot-initrd...ok
```

This is the server log when the blade PXE boots

```bsh
myuser@blade-one:~$ tail -f /var/log/maas/rackd.log
2018-01-28 15:59:54 provisioningserver.rpc.clusterservice: [info] Fully connected to all 4 event-loops on all 1 region controllers (blade-one).
2018-01-28 15:59:55 provisioningserver.rpc.clusterservice: [info] Rack controller 'fddh8e' registered (via blade-one:pid=1748) with MAAS version 2.4.2-7034-g2f5deb8b8-0ubuntu1.
2018-01-28 15:59:55 provisioningserver.rpc.clusterservice: [info] Rack controller 'fddh8e' registered (via blade-one:pid=1750) with MAAS version 2.4.2-7034-g2f5deb8b8-0ubuntu1.
2018-01-28 15:59:55 provisioningserver.rpc.clusterservice: [info] Rack controller 'fddh8e' registered (via blade-one:pid=1751) with MAAS version 2.4.2-7034-g2f5deb8b8-0ubuntu1.
2018-01-28 15:59:55 provisioningserver.rpc.clusterservice: [info] Rack controller 'fddh8e' registered (via blade-one:pid=1749) with MAAS version 2.4.2-7034-g2f5deb8b8-0ubuntu1.
2018-01-28 15:59:55 provisioningserver.utils.services: [info] New interface monitoring state: {'enp5s0': {'neighbour': False, 'mdns': True}, 'enp6s0': {'neighbour': True, 'mdns': True}, 'ens1f0': {'neighbour': True, 'mdns': True}, 'ens1f1': {'neighbour': False, 'mdns': True}, 'virbr0': {'neighbour': True, 'mdns': True}}
2018-01-28 15:59:55 provisioningserver.utils.services: [info] Starting neighbour discovery for interfaces: {'ens1f0', 'virbr0', 'enp6s0'}
2018-01-28 15:59:55 provisioningserver.utils.services: [info] Neighbour observation process for ens1f0 started.
2018-01-28 15:59:55 provisioningserver.utils.services: [info] Neighbour observation process for virbr0 started.
2018-01-28 15:59:55 provisioningserver.utils.services: [info] Neighbour observation process for enp6s0 started.
2018-01-28 15:59:55 provisioningserver.utils.services: [info] mDNS observation process started.
2018-01-28 15:59:55 sstreams: [info] maas:v2:download/maas:boot:grub-efi-signed:amd64:generic:uefi: to_add=['20190404.0'] to_remove=[]
2018-01-28 15:59:55 sstreams: [info] maas:v2:download/maas:boot:grub-efi:arm64:generic:uefi: to_add=['20190404.0'] to_remove=[]
2018-01-28 15:59:55 sstreams: [info] maas:v2:download/maas:boot:grub-ieee1275:ppc64el:generic:open-firmware: to_add=['20190506.0'] to_remove=[]
2018-01-28 15:59:55 sstreams: [info] maas:v2:download/maas:boot:pxelinux:i386:generic:pxe: to_add=['20180807.0'] to_remove=[]
2018-01-28 15:59:55 sstreams: [info] maas:v2:download/maas:boot:ubuntu:amd64:ga-18.04-lowlatency:bionic: to_add=['20190814'] to_remove=[]
2018-01-28 15:59:55 sstreams: [info] maas:v2:download/maas:boot:ubuntu:amd64:ga-18.04:bionic: to_add=['20190814'] to_remove=[]
2018-01-28 15:59:55 sstreams: [info] maas:v2:download/maas:boot:ubuntu:amd64:hwe-18.04-edge:bionic: to_add=['20190814'] to_remove=[]
2018-01-28 15:59:55 sstreams: [info] maas:v2:download/maas:boot:ubuntu:amd64:hwe-18.04-lowlatency-edge:bionic: to_add=['20190814'] to_remove=[]
2018-01-28 15:59:55 sstreams: [info] maas:v2:download/maas:boot:ubuntu:amd64:hwe-18.04-lowlatency:bionic: to_add=['20190814'] to_remove=[]
2018-01-28 15:59:55 sstreams: [info] maas:v2:download/maas:boot:ubuntu:amd64:hwe-18.04:bionic: to_add=['20190814'] to_remove=[]
2018-01-28 15:59:56 provisioningserver.utils.services: [info] observe-arp[ens1f0]: tcpdump: listening on ens1f0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 64 bytes
2018-01-28 15:59:56 provisioningserver.utils.services: [info] observe-arp[virbr0]: tcpdump: listening on virbr0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 64 bytes
2019-08-21 11:39:16 provisioningserver.utils.services: [info] observe-arp[enp6s0]: tcpdump: listening on enp6s0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 64 bytes
2019-08-21 11:39:19 provisioningserver.rackdservices.dhcp_probe_service: [info] Probe for external DHCP servers started on interfaces: ens1f0, enp6s0, virbr0.
2019-08-21 11:39:39 provisioningserver.dhcp.detect: [info] External DHCP server(s) discovered on interface 'enp6s0': <OFFICE_DHCP_SERVER_IP>
2019-08-21 11:39:49 provisioningserver.rackdservices.dhcp_probe_service: [info] External DHCP probe complete.
2019-08-21 11:47:39 provisioningserver.rackdservices.tftp: [info] pxelinux.0 requested by <BLADE_2_MAC_ADDRESS>
2019-08-21 11:47:39 provisioningserver.rackdservices.tftp: [info] pxelinux.0 requested by <BLADE_2_MAC_ADDRESS>
2019-08-21 11:47:39 provisioningserver.rackdservices.tftp: [info] ldlinux.c32 requested by <BLADE_2_MAC_ADDRESS>
2019-08-21 11:47:39 provisioningserver.rackdservices.tftp: [info] pxelinux.cfg/40a55f1c-cea7-e511-bb26-020ba5d5cb1c requested by <BLADE_2_MAC_ADDRESS>
2019-08-21 11:47:39 provisioningserver.rackdservices.tftp: [info] pxelinux.cfg/<BLADE_2_MAC_ADDRESS_WITH_DASHES> requested by <BLADE_2_MAC_ADDRESS>
2019-08-21 11:47:39 provisioningserver.rackdservices.tftp: [info] pxelinux.cfg/0A0A0ABF requested by <BLADE_2_MAC_ADDRESS>
2019-08-21 11:47:39 provisioningserver.rackdservices.tftp: [info] pxelinux.cfg/0A0A0AB requested by <BLADE_2_MAC_ADDRESS>
2019-08-21 11:47:39 provisioningserver.rackdservices.tftp: [info] pxelinux.cfg/0A0A0A requested by <BLADE_2_MAC_ADDRESS>
2019-08-21 11:47:39 provisioningserver.rackdservices.tftp: [info] pxelinux.cfg/0A0A0 requested by <BLADE_2_MAC_ADDRESS>
2019-08-21 11:47:39 provisioningserver.rackdservices.tftp: [info] pxelinux.cfg/0A0A requested by <BLADE_2_MAC_ADDRESS>
2019-08-21 11:47:39 provisioningserver.rackdservices.tftp: [info] pxelinux.cfg/0A0 requested by <BLADE_2_MAC_ADDRESS>
2019-08-21 11:47:39 provisioningserver.rackdservices.tftp: [info] pxelinux.cfg/0A requested by <BLADE_2_MAC_ADDRESS>
2019-08-21 11:47:39 provisioningserver.rackdservices.tftp: [info] pxelinux.cfg/0 requested by <BLADE_2_MAC_ADDRESS>
2019-08-21 11:47:39 provisioningserver.rackdservices.tftp: [info] pxelinux.cfg/default requested by <BLADE_2_MAC_ADDRESS>
2019-08-21 11:47:39 provisioningserver.rackdservices.tftp: [info] ubuntu/amd64/ga-18.04/bionic/daily/boot-kernel requested by <BLADE_2_MAC_ADDRESS>
2019-08-21 11:47:40 provisioningserver.rackdservices.tftp: [info] ubuntu/amd64/ga-18.04/bionic/daily/boot-initrd requested by <BLADE_2_MAC_ADDRESS>
2019-08-21 11:48:11 rackd: [info] 10.10.10.191 GET /images/ubuntu/amd64/ga-18.04/bionic/daily/squashfs HTTP/1.1 --> 200 OK (referrer: -; agent: Wget)
2019-08-21 11:49:09 provisioningserver.rackdservices.dhcp_probe_service: [info] Probe for external DHCP servers started on interfaces: ens1f0, enp6s0, virbr0.
2019-08-21 11:49:29 provisioningserver.dhcp.detect: [info] External DHCP server(s) discovered on interface 'enp6s0': <OFFICE_DHCP_SERVER_IP>
```

Blade 1, where MAAS is installed is `Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-58-generic x86_64)` and MAAS is `2.4.2-7034-g2f5deb8b8-0ubuntu1`

I followed these steps for installation:

- Installed the maas package with `sudo apt install maas`
- Added the first admin user with `sudo maas init` (Didn't add any ssh key)
- Logged in to http://:5240/MAAS/ and left all with default values. On the keys step added an ssh key generated for the blade-one server
- Under Subnets accessed the VLAN for the subnet where the other blades will PXE boot and did "Provide DHCP"
- Configured Blade 2 to PXE boot and booted

Answer (score 0):

The solution was on the MAAS settings, General tab. I had to set the Global Kernel Parameters to `console=ttyS0,115200`